# How can the access to internet be blocked using the proxy?

Tags: titanium-web-proxy

If i use the titanium proxy and with a button click, i would like to block the connection to internet.. and with a button click i would like to activate the internet access, how could this be achieved?

I would be normaly connected to my internet, but whatever i search in the internet it would be like i dont have access to the internet...

Thanks for the help.

I would need that function because i would like to use it in my project where i can disable and enable the internet access without having to deactivate any network adapters..

I don't know this could be achieved.